# Is this device claiming to reduce electricity bill a scam?

Tags: power-electronics, supercapacitor, power-factor-correction

I saw something on the net and I have no doubt that it is a scam. This advertises as 90% reduction of electricity bill in a houshold.

I have no idea what it does. From the looks of it it is just a filter (or maybe a PFC thing?) and it seems to have some sort of super cap (the gray box with epoxy resin)
I have a hardtime beleving this.

Is this even possible?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does the top and other side of the gray box show?

Comment: Complete nonesense. In theory, a cap could increase power factor to compensate for inductive loads. But it's too small to matter. And what if your power factor is bad because of capacitive loads? And in most cases, residential users don't pay for power factor anyway.

Comment: Does that label really say "Useful load: 28000W"? Please don't try to put 100s of amps through that! Also, please provide a link to the "product" in question. (Yes, it's a scam.)

Comment: @JRE shows nothing .... a mistery!

Comment: @TypeIA I did no add a link because of possible problems :D but you can search for "voltbox"  to find it

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J86QK0Njfv4

Comment: The black box just contains a normal main voltage rated capacitor (motor capacitor) and some epoxy to hide it.

Comment: Well, there is a test of that thing in a german tech magazine (heise) https://www.heise.de/tests/Warum-das-Stromsparkaestchen-Voltbox-nutzloser-Nepp-ist-6266294.html But I think you know that, you used the same images ;)

Comment: @jwsc yeah I saw it there but it worths to hear more opinions from the pro users here :)

Comment: I don't understand why  the downvotes for this -- should people feel guilty for wanting to know if others are scamming them? What is the message OP should take from it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is a scam.

Usually those devices are just capacitors connected to mains.

Apparently to fix the power factor, but rarely residetial buildings are inductive so this just adds capacitive load.

Sometimes the capacitor is not even connected to mains due to manufacturing error or it may just be made to look like it is connected so the mystery capacitor can be anything as it is not connected.

The schematics indicates there is something suspicious going on if the mystery box is drawn to the fuse like that.

The rest of the device is just a circuit to light up the LED so it just consumes power and does not save anything.

Answer (score 6):

From the markings on the board, you are looking at a "Motex SD008 Plug-In Energy Saving Device."

Besides being a scam, there is a [safety recall out for it in the UK.](https://www.gov.uk/product-safety-alerts-reports-recalls/product-recall-motex-sd008-plug-in-energy-saving-device-2204-0026)

It seems the plug is not an approved type, and that the fuse and MOV are inadequate to prevent a fire in case of overvoltage or a short circuit.

The idea seems to be that it draws off "voltage spikes" through the big gray thing (presumably a capacitor.)  Since the gray thing isn't really connected (the "copper pad" won't pass any real amount of current to the so-called filter,) the gray thing may be nothing more than a plastic box with wires epoxied in.  It may also really be a cheap capacitor - the ratings don't matter since it isn't really in the circuit.  It might have been cheaper for the manufacturer to use a real capacitor than to make a fake part.

The "filter" is just a decoy to make you think there's something going on.

Along with not doing anything to reduce your electric bill, the power supply for the LED is probably wasting several watts of power - all day, every day.  It is a variant of a capacitive dropper power supply, but it has resistors in places that ensure that a fairly high current will flow at all times.

It is a dangerous piece of junk that'll cost you money even if it doesn't burn your house down.

---

User jwsc provided a [link to the source for the images in the question,](https://www.heise.de/tests/Warum-das-Stromsparkaestchen-Voltbox-nutzloser-Nepp-ist-6266294.html) including the photos and the schematic.

Included in the (German lanuguage) article is an X-ray picture of the mysterious gray box.  It is indeed nothing more than a plastic box with wires stuck in it.  It is not a capicitor or any other electronic component.

The article confirms that the gadget draws current all the time.  Less than my eyeball estimate (I guessed a few watts, they measure 0.3W,) but still a lot considering that all it does is light up an LED.

The thing is a scam.  It is expensive and wastes energy.

Comment: OP has a euro plug version, so the plug issue may not be relevant. Then again, I wouldn't be surprised if the euro plug version also breaks and leaves pins in the socket.

Answer (score -1):

There is no actual device that decreases the energy bill and if it really does it would be fully illegal way. A super capacitor cannot decrease the consumption neither mock the provider. The only way you can really save power is by buying well optimized products that have good energy class or connect your own source of power like solar panels etc.

Comment: Active power filters, power factor correctors, etc.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Residential consumers typically don't have to pay for poor power factor.  But for industrial users, yes PFC will lower the bill.

Comment: @OskarSkog I as commenting on this part: "*There is no actual device that decreases the energy bill*".

Comment: I use a PV panel + an on-grid inverter. Works for me and is both legal and honest.

Comment: @fraxinus what is that thing?

Comment: "There is no actual device that decreases the energy bill"  Hey!  Is too -- it's called "the off switch".  But having your cake and eating it too?  No.

Comment: @OskarSkog This is also not true: "*if it really does it would be fully illegal way*". Since there is no mention of residential, or industrial consumers, not having an APF in an industrial zone will mean your bill will go up. And having an APF will not be illegal. So I really don't see why this answer has been upvoted. And my comment is not out of place.

Comment: @TimWescott "off switch" is 20th century, today we have the two states "on" and "onner"